# retrieving record from database using cursor in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have used following codes to retrieve record:

```
String getCredentialsFromAdmint(String name ,String pwd) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ADMIN, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_A_USER_NAME, KEY_A_PWD }, KEY_A_USER_NAME + "=?" + " AND " + KEY_A_PWD + "=?",
                new String[] { name , pwd }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(1);
        }
        else{
            return "norecord";
        }
```

---

This code works if there is a record but if no record is found then application gets an error.
Is there any other ways to retrieve data from database?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to following

```
 if ( cursor.moveToFirst()){
      return cursor.getString(1);
    } else{
        return "norecord";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns true;

It should looks like this:

```
if (cursor != null) {
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_A_USER_NAME));
   } else{
     //no record
   }
} else {
   //invalid uri
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code instead

```
if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    return cursor.getString(1);
    }
    else
    {
    return "norecord";
    }
}
else{
    return "norecord";
}
```